# LImit Access on pages. to prevent access pages without login

Tags: laravel, authentication, limit

as we know when we code on localhost we can go directly to dashboard admin on our website without login first by typing the link. so how we can stop that? so if we want to access the admin dashboard we really have to log in first

Answer (score 1):

use laravel middleware to limit accesses ... you can use auth middleware like:

```
Route::get('/profile', function () {
//  
})->middleware('auth');
```

for more info visit [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-groups)

Answer (score 1):

use laravel middleware in your web.php if you are using a simple function for your route

```
Route::get('/admin/dashboard',function () { 
return view....``
})->middleware('auth');
```

Or you can use a constructor in your Controller to limit access for all function in this controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```